# Addition and += give different results for list (depth first search)

Tags: python, list, depth-first-search

I've been trying to understand depth first search, and using various sources online obtained the following code:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'D'], 'B': ['E'], 'C': [], 'D': ['C', 'E'], 
         'E': ['H', 'I', 'J'], 'F': [], 'G': [], 'H': ['F'], 
         'I': [], 'J': ['G']}

def dfs(graph, start, end, path=None):
    if path == None:
        path = []
    path = path + [start]
    paths = []
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    for neighbour in graph[start]:
        if neighbour not in path:
            paths.extend(dfs(graph, neighbour, end, path))
    return paths

print(dfs(graph, 'A', 'G'))
```

This outputs the desired result:

```
[['A', 'B', 'E', 'J', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'E', 'J', 'G']]
```

But when I replace the line `path = path + [start]` with `path += [start]` (or `path.extend([start])`, which I understand does the same thing) I get the following output: `[['A', 'B', 'E', 'H', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'G', 'D', 'C']]`

I know this is to do with a difference in the operations, but I don't really understand how it applies here. Please could someone explain this?

Comment: You should avoid setting default mutable argument like `path=[]`, which is a  common gotcha in python (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: Edited! Thanks for that lesson :-)

Comment: didn't see that. but the problem persists after editing, probably, since OP didn't use `dfs` with a default argument anyway.

Comment: It does. It's an aside (and not an important one in this case, since the function is called only once) but one that taught me something I should know! And yes, the problem persists.

Comment: my answer completely ignored this(since I didn't see the [least atonishment and mutable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) issue)

Comment: Current code outputs: `[['A', 'B', 'E', 'H', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'G', 'D', 'C']]` and not `[['A', 'B', 'E', 'J', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'E', 'J', 'G']]` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @mso that's right.

Comment: Sorry, fixed now,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this

```
path = path + [start]
```

is slightly different than

```
path += [start]  # or path.extend([start])
```

for *lists* (and other mutable types) because it recreates a new reference of `path` (implicitly what you want, you don't want to write into the previous reference)

```
path += [start]  # or path.extend([start])
```

reuses the same reference because you're passing `path` many times here in your loop (without making a copy):

```
for neighbour in graph[start]:
    if neighbour not in path:
       paths.extend(dfs(graph, neighbour, end, path))
```

so if some other object has it in storage, you're changing both lists: not the same behaviour, not the behaviour you want.

Of course you could do `paths.extend(dfs(graph, neighbour, end, path.copy()))` but that would be against the principle of least atonishment for the caller (which doesn't expect the last parameter to be modified)

My advice:

- If you want performance and you don't care about reusing the reference or not, always use `+=` for lists because it just extends the list. The `+` operator creates a new list and copies, which is really slower.
- when using `path = path + something` with a `list` type, always include a comment for future maintainers (including yourself!) *not to optimize* that with `+=`.

maybe some more explicit and equivalent code:

```
path = path.copy() # or path[:], or list(path)...: force creation of a new reference to break dependency with passed parameter
path += [start]
```

Also note: it doesn't apply to `str` or `tuple` type because even `+=` creates a new reference, because of the string *immutability*. No risk of sharing references with strings, so using `tuple` instead of `list` here would have fixed it as well:

```
if path == None:
    path = tuple()
path += (start,)  # += creates a new path reference, cos path is a tuple, immutable
```

(but don't expect more performance with `+=` in that case, copies are made)

Comment: good advice but doesn't answer the question as to why OP got different results

Comment: @ShpielMeister There were basically 2 big mistakes in that code, which confused readers. Now that OP fixed the argument one (which didn't change anything but still...), my answer answers :) I just love that site :) thanks.

Comment: else, it would have been another sad duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument